# Openapi generator angular not generating multipart formdata endpoint correctly. (useForm is false by default)

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, swagger

This is the endpoint I have:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/file-upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public List<FileReference> handleFileUpload(
        @RequestPart(value = "file", name = "file") MultipartFile[] file, @ApiIgnore HttpSession session) {
    return service.handleFileUpload(
            Arrays.stream(file).map(MultipartFileWithUUID::new).collect(Collectors.toList()),
            session);
}
```

This is the generated endpoint in the swagger.json (swagger 2.0):

```
...
  "post": {
        "tags": [
          "damage-report-controller"
        ],
        "summary": "handleFileUpload",
        "operationId": "handleFileUploadUsingPOST",
        "consumes": [
          "multipart/form-data"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "file",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "file"
            },
            "collectionFormat": "multi"
          }
        ],
...
```

And here is the generated function:

```
 public handleFileUploadUsingPOST(file?: Array<Blob> ...) {

let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

header settings etc...

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        const consumes: string[] = [
            'multipart/form-data'
        ];


        const canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);

        let formParams: { append(param: string, value: any): any; };
        let useForm = false;

...
        if (useForm) {
            formParams = new FormData();
        } else {
            formParams = new HttpParams({encoder: this.encoder});
        }
...
}
```

The error I have is `415: Unsupported media type.`

I don't know how it should be generated correctly, but I changed `let useForm;` to true and it works,
so my guess that `let useForm = canConsumeForm(consumes)` because `canConsumeForm` returns a boolean.

What should I change so it gets generated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone reads this, I haven't found the proper solution using swagger 2.0, so I updated to openapi 3.0 and that fixed the problem.

[Apparently swagger 2.0 doesn't support uploading an array of files](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20uploading%20an%20arbitrary%20number%20of%20files%20(an%20array%20of%20files)%20is%20not%20supported.%20There%20is%20an%20open%20feature%20request%20at%20https%3A//github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254.%20For%20now%2C%20you%20can%20use%20a%20binary%20string%20array%20as%20a%20workaround%20for%20uploading%20an%20arbitrary%20number%20of%20files%3A), even though the only problem was that the generated service didn't use existing functions properly.